# What is difference between restlet,suitelet,suite talk

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

1)Comparing with in Restlet,suitelet and suitetalk
In which scenarios we mostly preferred to use restlet,
In which scenarios we mostly preferred to use suitelet,
In which scenarios we mostly preferred to use suitetalk.
anyone can help

2)what is difference between workflow and suite script. what is governance limit for workflow .what are the scenarios we prefer workflow than suite scripts.

3)We use client script for client side validations purpose,what are the scenarios we user event script for server side validations and what is the main purpose of user event script .

4)howmany types of suitelets are in netsuite and what are the use cases.can we implement netsuite custom pages using backend suitelet.

5)Can we Implement multi threading using schedule script for 1000 search requests(100 search requests on each thread).if yes,then how can we implement it?

Answer (score 12):

You mixing in your questions alot of different features of Netsuite. Im going to try and explain them one by one. Im going to assume you know how to create script records and are somewhat familiar with NetSuite

**Restlets and Suitelets**
These are both hosted in NetSuite by creating script records. The main difference between the two is:

Restlets: Can be used with *get, post, put, delete* requests, this makes it ideal if you are building and API which you can use in another application.

Suitelets: Can be used with *get, post*. Can be used along with Netsuites server widgets to make native looking Netsuite HTML pages. Can also technically be used for as an API

**SuiteScript**
Sounds scary but this is NetSuites scripting language built on top of Javascript (ES5 for now). If you know JS you shouldnt have an issue learning SuiteScript. The Restlets and Suitelets make use of SuiteScript. SuiteScript is also used for example in what netsuite calls "User Event Scripts". You can have custom SuiteScript code execute on events like "beforeLoad", "afterSubmit", "beforeSubmit"

**Workflows**
So we mention User Event Scripts. Well these are scripts that only a programmer can create. Workflows allows an average user to execute actions using diagrams kind of like a visual user event script.

**SuiteTalk**
Unlike Restlets and Suitelets, SuiteTalk is and independent app built outside of NS. I believe they have support for C#, Java and maybe PHP. These are built using a WSDL provided by NS.

*Can we Implement multi threading using schedule script for 1000 search requests(100 search requests on each thread).if yes,then how can we implement it?*
   I generally just execute the search again if theres more there is 1000 results and keep merging the lists untill its done.